# I'm still baffled as to why this program doesn't produce the result that i expect it would

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream, filewriter, printwriter

I still can't figure out why this program doesn't compute and give the result which i thought it would.

I'm trying to use an instance of the PrintWriter class to write several floating-point values, specified by the user in a for loop, to a text file named by the user as Numbers.txt.

Then i created an object, inputFile, of the Scanner class and use the hasNext method to read those values in a while loop, in which they're calculated and the result is assigned to the total variable; an accumulator initialized to 0.0.

Nevertheless, the value of the total variable is still 0.0, not the accumulation of those floating-point values in the file.

I'm a novice to Java particularly and programming in general, so somebody please help me identify where it went wrong and how to fix it in order to get the desired result.

Thanks in advance! Below is the code section that i wrote:

```
public class FileSum {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      double individualValues, total = 0.0; // total is an accumulator to store the sum of the values specified in Numbers.txt, thus it must be initialized to 0.0
      int numberOfValues;
    
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    
      System.out.print("enter the file name: ");
      String fileName = kb.nextLine();
    
      System.out.print("enter the number of floating-point values in the file: ");
      numberOfValues = kb.nextInt();
    
      PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    
      for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfValues; i++) {
          System.out.print("the floating-point value number " + i + ": ");
          individualValues = kb.nextDouble();
          outputFile.println(individualValues);
      }
    
      File file = new File(fileName);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    
      while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
          individualValues = inputFile.nextDouble();
          total = total + individualValues;
      }
    
      inputFile.close();
      outputFile.close();
      kb.close();
    
      System.out.println("the total values in Numbers.txt: " + total);
  }}
```

Here's the program output:

> enter the file name: Numbers.txt
>
> enter the number of floating-point values in the file: 2
>
> the floating-point value number 1: 4.5
>
> the floating-point value number 2: 3.2
>
> the total values in Numbers.txt: 0.0

Comment: What's the output you expect, and what's the actual output? (And what was the input that produced that output?)

Comment: Hi Radiodef, the output that i expect is the accumulation of the floating-point values specified by the user. So, for example, if the user is prompted to enter 2 values, 4.5 and 3.2 respectively. Then the total value accumulated in Numbers.txt would be 7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to read some values from System.in, write them to a file, then read that file and add the numbers.

However, since you are not closing the file that you are writing until the end of the program, you cannot be sure that the file contents are flushed to the file when you read the file. So you are likely `inputFile.hasNext()` is always returning false

Just move the line `outputFile.close();` up in your code, so it happens before you create the Scanner on the new File then you should be good!
The file will be written, then you can open it for reading.

**Further explanation** This is due to `PrintWriter` not automatically flushing it's output when you call println. It stays in a buffer for performance reasons. There are other constructors that take a autoFlush Boolean value. If set to true it will flush the values you wrote to the file. By calling close you are flushing anything that is waiting to be written, and then front up any resources that are tied up on this open file.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i was trying to do with the program. Btw, thank you so much because i did what you suggested and it worked! I moved the outputFile.close() statement up the code, so it's placed between the for loop and File file = new File(fileName). Could you explain to me further why this approach works? I'm still quite confused about this unfortunately.